# FromSql throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have troubles in understanding the FromSql clause that calls a storedprocedure.
What I want to achieve:
I want to query a user with a username and password. If I type in the correct credentials, all works fine. The FromSql clause fills up my Object with the values. Fine so far. What bothers my is following scenario: If I start the application fresh and type in the wrong credentials ***the first time*** I get following exception:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Error: An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query for context type 'xyz.DatabaseContext'.
System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'Id' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.
```

I also understand that exception. The stored procedure returns 0 if no user is found and EF tries to map this "empty" result into the object which fails.

Now here is the strange thing: If I try it with a user withvalid credentials and ***afterwards*** type in wrong credentials, no exception occurs. The queryResult has a count of 0, which is kind of expected. This confuses me. Why is it failing on the first "wrong" try and working afterwards a successful result is returned?

Here is the call of the storedprocedure:

```
queryResult = await mDatabaseContext.MyModelObject
         .FromSql($"myStoredProcedure {null}, {username}, {password}, {null}, {null}, {null}")
         .OrderBy(x => x.ID).ToListAsync();
```

Configuration:
In `Startup.cs` I add the DatabaseContext as singleton

```
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")),
        ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

I use the DatabaseContext via Dependency-Injection where I call the FromSql which I described above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us the SQL of your stoed procedure? Because it works when data are found and don't when none means a lot that the issue may come from your stored procedure.

Comment: Sadly I am not allowed (company restrictions). When I execute the stored procedure directly in SQL Server Management Studio with correct username and password it returns several rows (customers with cards). When I add incorrect username and / or password, the stored procedure returns 0 (zero)

Comment: What I have to add is the following: MyModelObject is not a database table. It is a object which the stored procedure returns when correct usercredentials are provided. Is it possible that it has something to do with that?

Comment: I would speculate and say that probably the first time sql is executed, EF Core uses the (expected) returned reader to verify the mappings. So the first execute should return reader with correct columns, even if there are no rows. I would suggest modifying the sp to return empty recordset (like `SELECT ... WHERE 1 = 0`) instead of 0.

Comment: I will give it a try! Thanks IvanStoev and CodeNotFound.